# Blackberry SOAP web service call without KSOAP

Tags: web-services, blackberry, soap

I've had nothing but problems using libraries that claim to simplify consuming SOAP Web Services. I've been using KSoap2 on the Blackberry to accomplish this, but I'm not liking the process at all.

On Android I manually created my envelopes with much success, I ended up doing the same on iPhone after much disappointment using SudzC.

I would like to do this for Blackberry as well. What classes should I use and how should I structure the envelope?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm consuming REST services that output XML documents, and we're doing all XML processing with the DOM libraries provided by RIM (using classes like net.rim.device.api.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder and net.rim.device.api.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory).

The HTTP part can be done Java ME IO support (with javax.microedition.io.HttpConnection). Making your own SOAP WS client sounds like a lot of work, but it can certainly be done.